# PIL.ImageFont cannot open font with space in name

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

sI am trying to use PIL.ImageFont.truetype to open a font
This is for an OCR project

I have been unable to find a solution in Google or this site so far.
The problem occurs when I try to open a font with spaces in the name.
Any font name without a space works fine

```
from PIL import ImageFont

#This Works
ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", 12)

#This does not
ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\Times New Roman.ttf", 12)
```

Error is here:

> File "B:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 145, in **init**
>     layout_engine=layout_engine)
>   OSError: cannot open resource

I've tried the following
1) renaming the file (not an elegant solution anyway)
2) moving the font to the same directory as the python script
3) adding / inside space (suggested)

I've also checked the error by trying multiple times with different font names and the same errors occur.

so far nothing works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I may have a solution. The hint came to me when I was typing in the font file name and a context menu appeared.

In the context menu was a list of fonts.
All the font names were changed to a single name.
For example "Time New Roman" was changed to "times"

I would be curious to know where this list exists.
I tried to find it but came up empty.

Also, In addition I wanted to work with a custom font that wasn't listed.
After downloading the font, I renamed it to a single word font.
Then I placed the font in the same directory as my python script.
This worked OK.

I thought I would post this in case anyone else had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This is not the string you think it is:

```
"C:\Windows\Fonts\Times New Roman.ttf"
```

Backslash is an escape character. You need to escape the backslash to have a real backslash, like this:

```
"C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Times New Roman.ttf"
```

You may also do this, if you prefer:

```
os.path.join('C:\\', 'Windows', 'Fonts', 'Times New Roman.ttf')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a list online with Font Names mapping to File Name. You can use the file name for the corresponding Font Name.

For Example:   for "Times New Roman"   we can  use "Times.ttf"

Please find the complete list in the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list